# MySql update each n-th rows without using module to avoid deadlock

Tags: mysql, deadlock

I have a few queries which are running simultaneously, and each query should update own n-th row depends on the number of queries I need to run. For example, we need to run 5 queries so where clause should be `where (id MOD :queries_amont) = :current_query_number`

but in such case, I'm getting deadlock and I think it's because MySql is scanning all rows to find correct rows to update as there is no index to use.

Is it possible to balance row updating between queries running simultaneously? Or how to avoid deadlocks with current implementation?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? What is the reason behind multiple queries?

Comment: I need to update the huge amount of data every minute. So by those update queries, I'm locking rows for further selection and manipulation with data. With a single query, it's taking to much time processing each row as I need to run API call to get fresh data for each individual row

Answer (score 1):

In general: if you have to run some statements constantly without any event, your database design probably is very bad. More so if those statements take a long time. So you should consider changing it.
To answer your question, you could use [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-frames.html) to only scope for every n-th row.

Comment: The issue is not in Db, I need to make API call for each row to update with fresh data, and running all in one process taking to much time even with running few async API calls, So was decided to make few commands to update those rows and each command should lock and update own rows

Comment: You can select all rows, use a window function to split them into small groups, lock the groups and do your stuff from here on

Comment: Thank yo!u I did not know about window functions, will try it